# Dockerfile not executing dotnet command in CMD

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a Dockerfile to build, publish and run a dotnet core application. The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.5-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/SomeDirectory/Some.csproj", "src/SomeDirectory/"]
COPY ["src/SomeDirectory/copy-certificate.sh", "copy-certificate.sh"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/SomeDirectory/Some.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/SomeDirectory"
RUN dotnet build "Some.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Some.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=build /src/copy-certificate.sh copy-certificate.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "copy-certificate.sh" ]
CMD ["dotnet", "Some.dll"]
```

Before running the `dotnet Some.dll` command, i want to execute an aws command within `copy-certificate.sh`, that copies a certificate to a location within container. So i added the following shell script as the EntryPoint of Dockerfile:

**copy-certificate.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
aws s3 cp s3://key/certificate.crt /root/directory/certificate.crt
exec "$@"
```

After creating the container, i try to run `docker start $CONTAINER`.

But i keep getting this error at this step `CMD ["dotnet", "Some.dll"]` while checking logs for the container:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I'm new to dockers. Please do correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: use different image

Comment: Change the ```CMD ["dotnet", "Some.dll"]``` back to ```ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Some.dll"]```. Then create the ```RUN aws s3 cp s3://key/certificate.crt /root/directory/certificate.crt``` after the ```COPY . .``` command and you will have to add the aws dependencies with ```RUN apt-get install aws``` or whatever inside the build container.

Comment: okay...why is it behaving like that though...any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround that i found to include `dotnet Some.dll` was to add it to copy-certificate.sh by substituting `dotnet` with its full path in linux server: `/usr/bin/dotnet`

**copy-certificate.sh** :

```
#!/bin/sh
aws s3 cp s3://key/certificate.crt /root/directory/certificate.crt
/usr/bin/dotnet Some.dll
exec "$@"
```

and remove the `CMD ["dotnet", "Some.dll"]` part within `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1):

So what's going on here is that the values in `CMD` are being passed as arguments to the command in `ENTRYPOINT`.  When you start your container it is essentially executing this:

```sh
/bin/bash copy-certificate.sh dotnet Some.dll
```

`ENTRYPOINT` is the command that gets executed when starting the container. In this case, `CMD` are the arguments that are passed to that command by default if you didn't provide arguments when running the container.

Because your script has the `exec "$@"` call, the script is handling the execution of `dotnet Some.dll`. The reason that fails with the error you're seeing is likely because Some.dll doesn't exist in your working directory or is named differently. I would suggest adding a `RUN` instruction to output the `/app` directory to verify its contents:

```
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN ls
```

The way that you're using these instructions is not the recommended way of doing things. I would suggest reading up more on the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) and [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) instructions and how they [interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).

A better way to do this would be to remove the script altogether and run your aws command as part of building the container image. You could change your `final` stage to the following (assuming you correct the path to Some.dll):

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=build /src/copy-certificate.sh copy-certificate.sh
RUN aws s3 cp s3://key/certificate.crt /root/directory/certificate.crt
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Some.dll"]
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation...i added dotnet path for linux `/usr/bin/dotnet Some.dll` and added it to copy-certificate.sh...that worked. I want this `/usr/bin/dotnet Some.dll` to be executed each time run command is used on docker file. So this needs to be present within copy-certificate.sh